# I want to view my recent Blog post on my footer (Magento)

Tags: magento

I am using this extension on Magento

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/nblog-blog-extension-by-neotheme.html

My blog page is working fine but i want show the recent 3 posts on my footer.

i am not getting any solution for it.
If any one Know this please help me

Answer (score 3):

Check your `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\neotheme\blog.xml`.

Add this code in the `<default>` tag

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="neotheme_blog/widget_post_list" name="blog.latest.posts"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Yes it is works but little confuse how can i add limit on it and can i control it post blog

Comment: @user3040570 i you can set limit on system configuration.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code in `default` tag of blog.xml

```
<block type="neotheme_blog/widget_post_list" after="blog.category.list" name="blog.latest.posts">
     <action method="setPostCount"><param>5</param></action>
</block>
```

where between param tag you can enter any digit. the blog will show the no. of posts accordingly.